# set boolean value into variable using JSTL tags?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am using JSTL tags. i have below code.

```
<c:set var="refreshSent" value="false"/>
```

Now variable **refreshSent** has boolean value or String?

Thanks!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It is going to be a boolean. You can check it by comparing in a

```
<c:if test="${refreshSent eq false}">
```

and

```
<c:if test="${refreshSent eq 'false'}">
```

The second is a string comparison.

Comment: I think that explicitly saying that the first will succeed and the second will fail will clarify the answer. I know it's silly, but I tend to go for the code and only later read the text. Thank you!

Comment: @Cristopher - Since `refreshSent` is actually a `String` with the value `"false"`, both calls will succeed.

Answer (score 12):

It is a `String`.

The following JSP code:

```
<c:set var="refreshSent" value="false" />
<c:set var="refreshSent2" value="${false}" />
<c:set var="refreshSent3" value="${'false'}" />

<div>
<div>${refreshSent} : ${refreshSent['class']}</div>
<div>${refreshSent2} : ${refreshSent2['class']}</div>
<div>${refreshSent3} : ${refreshSent3['class']}</div>
</div>
```

Outputs the following in a browser:

```
false : class java.lang.String
false : class java.lang.Boolean
false : class java.lang.String
```

But if you use the `refreshSent` variable in an EL expression where a `boolean` is expected, it will be converted to a `boolean` by a call to `Boolean.valueOf(String)` (according to the [JSP Specification](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jsp-2.1-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/jsp-2_1-fr-spec-el.pdf?AuthParam=1546930247_27b70ab135973a22fa114e23cfd73260)).

So if you use:

```
<c:if test="${refreshSent}">
```

the value of the `test` attribute will be set to a boolean `false` value. The `${refreshSent}` expression results in a `String`, but since the `test` attribute expects a `boolean`, a call to `Boolean.valueOf("false")` is made.

Answer (score 6):

I use this for boolean

```
<c:set var="refreshSent" value="${false}"/>
<c:if test="${refreshSent}">
    some code ........
</c:if>
```

Comment: Both value="${false}" and value="false" evaluate to the same thing in your test... so if you're looking to save characters, just use value="false" (forgoing the ${ } bit...).

Answer (score 3):

```
<c:set var="refreshSent" value="false"/>
```

If the expression in `value` evaluates to `String`; then the value of `var refreshSent` is of type `String`.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/ for reference.

There is automatic type conversion done behind the scenes.

See http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2003/10/07/jstl1.html

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's can be boolean and String.

```
<c:if test="${refreshSent}">
    your code...
</c:if>
```

or you can use like this

```
<c:if test="${refreshSent eq 'false'}">
    your code...
</c:if>
```

Thanks.