# How to check a JSTL Variable in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jstl, struts

In my JSP, I use JSTL to set a certain variable:

```
<c:set var="myVar" value="true" scope="request" />
```

Then in jQuery, in $(document).ready(function() {..}), I need to check the value of "myVar".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      if ("$(requestScope.myVar}") {
         // Case 1
      }
      else {
         // Case 2
      }
   });
</script>
```

This is not working. The 'if' condition always evaluates to `TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, `$`**(**`requestScope.myVar}` must be `$`**{**`requestScope.myVar}` (note the first paranthesis).

Also, you should use

`$`{requestScope.myVar eq true} for Boolean comparison

and

`$`{requestScope.myVar eq 'true'} for String comparison

See here: [set boolean value into variable using JSTL tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512547/set-boolean-value-into-variable-using-jstl-tags)

Answer (score 0):

The variable you set is server-side, so your javascript after the page is rendered will look like

```
if ("true") {
   // Case 1
}
else {
   // Case 2
}
```

To check the variable on the server-side while the page is rendering you should use JSTL

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${requestScope.myVar}">         
    // Case 1
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    // Case 2
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```